# How to copy of my Visual Basic program (source code and form)

Tags: visual-studio, copy

How do I make a copy of  a Visual Basic solution/project/program with a different name in Visual Studio 2019? ...there is no "File > Save As" available!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Visual Studio doesn't have a good way to do this. I've found that the fastest method is:

1. In the Windows File Explorer, copy the folder containing the project.
2. Move that copied folder to the path that you would like for your duplicated project.
3. Rename the folder to be the new project name.
4. Open the newly renamed folder.
5. You'll see a folder with the old project name. Rename that to the new project name.
6. You'll see three files with the old project name. Rename all of those, so that they use the new project name.
7. Open `<NewProjectName>.sln` in a text editor, such as NotePad, TextPad, NotePad++, etc.
8. Change all instances of the old project name to be the new project name.
9. Open `<NewProjectName>.vbproj` in a text editor.
10. Change all instances of the old project name to be the new project name.

That's it! You can now open the `sln` file and it should work immediately.

Comment: Thank you. That is kinda what I did while I was waiting for a reply. It worked!

Comment: You're welcome! I do this task a lot and I find it a bit strange that there's no in-built way to do it, but at least it's fairly quick to do manually.